# Import Plugin Entries Not Loading

Tags: plugins, import

I am using the import plugin by Bob Oldehampsink to load entries. I have 47 fields that I'm uploading. The import shows as uploaded successfully in the admin and the file is my assets but the entries do not load.  If I reduce the number of fields the entry appears as it should. I can't find any errors related to the plugin. Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Check for PHP errors in your PHP log. It's possible PHP is running out of memory while trying to perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to the bottom of this and the problem was that 2 columns in my CSV file had the same name.

If you have a similar problem check the "craft_import_log" table in your database. You will find the error reporting for the import plugin there. The error I received was "Columns and data did not match, could be due to malformed CSV row."

I ran my CSV through an online checker and it informed me that there were duplicate column headings. Renaming one of the columns fixed my issue.